# Google Tag Manager display blank page

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I was trying to implement a Google Tag Manager into my website but strangely when I had it and refresh my page it goes all Blank. (No specific error).

I tried the only upvoted solution from this thread that has no accepted answer yet : [Same question 1year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332024/google-tag-manager). Still, this is not working for me.

I really dont get what is wrong with it (console is clean).

If someone has an idea feel free to suggest.

### Tag for beter comprehension

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

### Edit :

I just tried it on an other website and it works without trouble.

And has a complement information : When I put the right Google Tag Manager on the site I'am working on, if I go for `View Page Source`. It's all blank and when I `Inspect` it this is the output :

[image]

### Edit 2 :

The part with only the `<noscript><iframe src="">.....</iframe></noscript>` is not the problem (if I leave it without the `function`) it works.
For more information, this is the Website I'm working on -> http://www.agencedevoyage.com/

### SOLVED

It was Smarty, this stupid thing does not recognise it as a function or I don't know exactly what was going on. Anyway the solution is to use those tags :
`{literal}....{/literal}`

Comment: @EikePierstorff I don't understand your answer :/
Do you imply that It could be The Google Tag Manager that is not good ?
Or that there is in my webpage an other tag somewhere that is making it buggy ?

Answer (score 1):

As say in my question I finally found the answer :

It was Smarty, which was not recognising GTM as a function or I don't know exactly what was going on. Anyway the solution is to use those tags : `{literal}....{/literal}`